# Туториал Google App Engine SDK for Python

Tags: python, sdk, google-app-engine

В туториале сказано, что для проверки проекта можно использовать команду `dev_appserver.py helloworld/`в директиве с проектом. При её использовании возникает вот такая ошибка. Как её исправить?  [image: ошибка]

Comment: Попробуйте без слэша, или с обратным `dev_appserver.py helloworld\\`. Это x-овый слэш, а у Вас Винда.

Comment: Спасибо, но ошибка остается той же.